# Codeigniter 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

I search for a long times and I finally found this 'search and view' tutorials in google but after I tried to run, It  show me '404 page not found'. Is there any mistakes? Please help me and thankyou. I'm really new for this.

this is controllers -> Search.php

```
<?php 
 function ajaxsearch()
    {

       if(is_null($this->input->get('id')))
        {

        $this->load->view('input');    


        }
        else
        {
        $this->load->model('Bookmodel'); 

        $data['booktable']=$this->Bookmodel->booktable($this->input->get('id')); 

        $this->load->view('output',$data);

        }


    }
```

this is model -> Bookmodel.php

```
<?php 

function booktable($search){

        $query = $this
                ->db
                ->select('jantina','bangsa','agama')
                ->from('pesakit')
                ->like('rn',$search)
                ->or_like('name',$search)
                ->get();

        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
            return $query->result(); 
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

}
```

this is views -> input.php

```
<div class="container">

 <!-- search box container starts  -->

    <div class="search">
        <div class="space"></div>
  <form action="" method="get">

      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
        <div class="input-group">

            <span class="input-group-addon" >BOOK SEARCH</span>
  <input autocomplete="off" id="search"  type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Search Book name or Author " >

        </div>
       </div>
      </div>   
      <div class="space"></div>
  </form>
     </div>  
  <!-- search box container ends  -->


     <div id="txtHint" style="padding-top:50px; text-align:center;" ><b>Book information will be listed here...</b></div>

</div>
<script>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#search").keyup(function(){
       var str=  $("#search").val();
       if(str == "") {
               $( "#txtHint" ).html("<b>Book information will be listed here...</b>"); 
       }else {
               $.get( "<?php echo base_url();?>home/ajaxsearch?id="+str, function( data ){
                   $( "#txtHint" ).html( data );  
            });
       }
   });  
});  
</script>
```

this is output Views -> output.php

```
<?php
    if(!empty($booktable ))  
 { 

      $output = '';
      $outputdata = '';  
      $outputtail ='';

      $output .= '<div class="container">
                   <div class="table-responsive">
                   <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                          <tr>
                  <th>Jantina</th>
                              <th>Bangsa</th>
                              <th>Agama</th>
                  </tr>

                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                   ';

      foreach ($booktable as $objects)    
       {   
           $outputdata .= ' 

                    <tr> 
                    <td >'.$objects->jantina.'</td>
                    <td >'.$objects->bangsa.'</td>
                    <td>'.$objects->agama.'</td>
                    </tr> 

           ';
        //  echo $outputdata; 

          }  

         $outputtail .= ' 
                         </tbody>
                         </table>
                         </div>
                         </div> ';

         echo $output; 
         echo $outputdata; 
         echo $outputtail; 
 }  

 else  
 {  
      echo 'Data Not Found';  
 }
```

Comment: When do you get the page not found error?

Comment: When I try to run http://localhost/project/index.php/search

Comment: Ok can you look into your HTML source in your browser and go look for the url in your $.get(.... ). What does that show?

Comment: $.get("<?php echo base_url();?>search/ajaxsearch?id="+str, function( data ){

Comment: When you put the URL in your browser to run this... And you do a View Source ( right mouse click - view source - or something like that.) and it shows you all the HTML that has been generated what do you see for the URL in .get() - the others have answered this but I want you to know how to Go Look and see what is happening.

Comment: did you mean View page resource?

Comment: Yes - something like that :)

Comment: I already view it just now when you asked me to but there doesn't have things start with 'get()'

Comment: Sorry - we are looking for the URL that is in the javascript in your $.get. We want to look at the URL and see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't find this `"<?php echo base_url();?>home/ajaxsearch?id="` and you are calling for **Search.php Controller** unless if you change the route of your search into **home/**, if not. Try this:

Replace this:

```
"<?php echo base_url();?>home/ajaxsearch?id="
```

With this:

```
"<?php echo base_url();?>search/ajaxsearch?id="
```

**Updated Answer:** for 404 message

For **Search.php Controller**
Replace your **ajaxsearch()**

with this:

```
function ajaxsearch()
{   
    $id = $this->input->get('id');
    if(isset($id)){
        $this->load->model('Bookmodel'); 

        $data['booktable']=$this->Bookmodel->booktable($this->input->get('id')); 

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    echo "error";
}
```

Comment: Put an echo("test"); die(); in the start of your ajaxsearch() and open it on your browser to test. Tell me if it works.

Comment: in controllers or ? views?

Comment: in search controller

Comment: Okay try to visit search/ajaxsearch?id=test .  in your browser

Comment: still the same, I see 'test'

Comment: Okay good. try this outside of your keyup .


               `$.get( "<?php echo base_url();?>home/ajaxsearch?id=test", function( data ){
                   $( "#txtHint" ).html( data );  
            });`

and just comment for now your keyup function to test

Comment: replace this .   $.get("<?php echo base_url();?>search/ajaxsearch?id="+str, function( data ) to this                $.get( "<?php echo base_url();?>home/ajaxsearch?id=test", function( data ){ $( "#txtHint" ).html( data ); });                 ?

Comment: still the same, 'test'

Comment: did you put it outside of keyup?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I don't know where's outside of keyup

Comment: ` $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#search").keyup(function(){
       var str=  $("#search").val();
       if(str == "") {
               $( "#txtHint" ).html("<b>Book information will be listed here...</b>"); 
       }else {
               $.get( "<?php echo base_url();?>home/ajaxsearch?id="+str, function( data ){
                   $( "#txtHint" ).html( data );  
            });
       }
   });  
}); `

Comment: replace it with this $.get( "<?php echo base_url();?>home/ajaxsearch?id=test", function( data ){ $( "#txtHint" ).html( data ); });

Comment: Hmm. then we have no problem for that script.  In your first run when you change home to search? is it a 404 error message?

Comment: yes. if I removed echo("test"); die(); , then i get 404 error message

Comment: So if you put your domain name with home/ajaxsearch?id=test on the end in your browser for the URL do you get the 404?

Comment: Message: Can't use method return value in write context
Filename: controllers/Search.php
Line Number: 5

Comment: if(isset($this->input->get('id'))){

Comment: 404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Comment: @bluetree - setting a variable and testing to see if it's set is a little anti useful... The CI get will return a value or be null So test for !empty would cover it better, but you want to check its an integer...

Comment: @flac Do you have all the view files created under your views folder?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I agree with you. The reason I tried this becauseI have an experience about this error and storing it to variable first fixed the error. I don't know why it throwing an error when you put it directly the $this->input->post/get to isset().

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Yes !empty should work. I forgot I about it haha

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Yes I did

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function in wrong format.

Change your url

```
"<?php echo base_url();?>home/ajaxsearch?id="
```

to

```
"<?php echo base_url();?>search/ajaxsearch?id="
```

Read more about codeigniter url routing from this [link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)